# How to Dynamically FIx the header Column width in React Bootstrap-Table-Next with respect to data cell

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

[image: In the Image as you can see width of header is change but data cell width are not accroding to the header]I'm able to change the Header Column Width but not able to change the data cell Width according to that respected column.
my code to change width for header is:

```
 columns: [
            {
                dataField: 'S_NO',
                text: 'S.No',
                sort: true,
                sortCaret: (order) => {
                    if (!order) return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp; ⇓⇑ </span>);
                    else if (order === 'asc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;⇓<font color="#808080">⇑</font></span>);
                    else if (order === 'desc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#D3D3D3">⇓</font>⇑</span>);
                    return null;
                },
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { textAlign: 'center', background: '#ffffff', color: '#808080', fontSize: "14px",width:"35px" };
                }
            },
            {
                dataField: 'language_name',
                text: 'Language',
                sort: true,
                sortCaret: (order) => {
                    if (!order) return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp; ⇓⇑ </span>);
                    else if (order === 'asc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;⇓<font color="#808080">⇑</font></span>);
                    else if (order === 'desc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#D3D3D3">⇓</font>⇑</span>);
                    return null;
                },
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { textAlign: 'center', background: '#ffffff', color: '#808080', fontSize: "14px",width:"30px"};
                }
            },
            {
                dataField: 'question_type',
                text: 'Question Type',
                sort: true,
                sortCaret: (order) => {
                    if (!order) return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp; ⇓⇑ </span>);
                    else if (order === 'asc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;⇓<font color="#808080">⇑</font></span>);
                    else if (order === 'desc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#D3D3D3">⇓</font>⇑</span>);
                    return null;
                },
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { textAlign: 'center', background: '#ffffff', color: '#808080', fontSize: "14px",width:"35px" };
                }
            },
            {
                dataField: 'question_desc',
                text: 'Question',
                sort: true,
                sortCaret: (order) => {
                    if (!order) return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp; ⇓⇑ </span>);
                    else if (order === 'asc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;⇓<font color="#808080">⇑</font></span>);
                    else if (order === 'desc') return (<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#D3D3D3">⇓</font>⇑</span>);
                    return null;
                },
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { textAlign: 'center', background: '#ffffff', color: '#808080', fontSize: "14px" };
                }
            }
        ]
```

Please help me out to change the cell width with respect to header width.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `table-layout: fixed`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using:-

```
style: () => {             
                    return {
                        width:"5px"
                    }
                }
```